# Empty record in Data Explorer query

Tags: support, bounties, data-explorer

When I run the following query on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries) the first record is empty - it's like a blank name. **Can someone please explain how the top bounty answerer is nothing?**

```
SELECT Top 139
       OwnerUserId As [User Link], 
       COUNT(*)    As BountiesWon
FROM 
    Votes v
    INNER JOIN Posts p ON v.PostId = p.Id
WHERE
  VoteTypeId=9
GROUP BY
  p.OwnerUserId
ORDER BY
  BountiesWon DESC
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Reasons:

Here are the reasons why the owner user id is displayed as blank:

- Bounties expired on those posts and no one was awarded the bounty.
- Bounty was awarded to a post without an owner (such as one by a since-deleted user)

Thanks to [@TimStone](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150235/tim-stone) for the second point.

#### Example:

For example, take a look at this question and the comment under that question. However, the bounty was not awarded to any of the answers.

[Jython Development on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/814845/jython-development-on-google-app-engine)

#### Comment states the following:

```
Added bounty on 24 Jan 2011. If someone has newer info on Jython, 
examples in use on appengine,source code, tutorials etc. 
please post – abel Jan 24 '11 at 9:58
```

Comment: Yep. The other scenario is that the bounty was awarded to a post without an owner (such as one by a since-deleted user)